# create a pandas frame of shape (x**0.5,x**0.5) from a array of size x python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of size 64, such has:

```
In[164]: x_y.values / x_ysquare.stack().values
Out[164]: 
array([ 1.        ,  0.01623716, -0.03305102,  0.03264311, -0.0175754 ,
        0.04017079,  0.15731795, -0.01797369,  0.01623716,  1.        ,
        0.08387368, -0.09562322,  0.02700502,  0.0614588 ,  0.03461564,
       -0.12421004, -0.03305102,  0.08387368,  1.        , -0.00248859,
       -0.00391474,  0.01603743,  0.05942098,  0.08989135,  0.03264311,
       -0.09562322, -0.00248859,  1.        , -0.16354249, -0.00887474,
        0.30343543,  0.12873483, -0.0175754 ,  0.02700502, -0.00391474,
       -0.16354249,  1.        ,  0.02347214, -0.30337839, -0.09302462,
        0.04017079,  0.0614588 ,  0.01603743, -0.00887474,  0.02347214,
        1.        , -0.01125003, -0.31859215,  0.15731795,  0.03461564,
        0.05942098,  0.30343543, -0.30337839, -0.01125003,  1.        ,
        0.18483076, -0.01797369, -0.12421004,  0.08989135,  0.12873483,
       -0.09302462, -0.31859215,  0.18483076,  1.        ])
```

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe of size 8x8 from those 64 data.

this is a correlation matrix where I am forcing the mean to be 0, I am trying to get the exact same output shape as if I were using df.corr() method.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do:

```
arr_reshaped = arr.reshape(8,8)

df = pd.DataFrame(arr_reshaped)
```